# Support for VMware Player by Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vmware-player

I ran into this issue as soon as I configured the *en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso* in VMware Player.

[image: Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you.]

How do I resolve this issue?

VMware Player goes into a restart loop. I know VMware Workstation 8 will be required.

Which version of VMware Player is supported with Windows 8?

Comment: Where did you find the iso? I bought windows 8, but can't find where to download it.

Comment: From here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed VMware Player Version 5.0.0 build-812388 and (.iso) Windows 8 is working fine. Earlier I had VMware Player 3.0.0 build.

Answer (score 2):

According to VMware, [the current player supports Windows 8 already](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/).

> VMware Player is the easiest way to run multiple operating systems at
>   the same time on your PC. With its user-friendly interface, VMware
>   Player makes it effortless for anyone to try out **Windows 8**, Windows 7,
>   Chrome OS, the latest Linux releases, or create isolated virtual
>   machines to safely test new software.

I'd make sure your ISO isn't corrupt.